# Add "test-" in domain part of the valid email address in C#

Tags: c#, email

I have a scenario, to convert the valid email address to test account by adding "test-" in the email address domain. So that on the testing environment it won't reach to the actual recipients. Also I adding my email address in the Bcc to verify that email content.

What I have tried so far:

```
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    // already valided the "emailAddress" is the valid one or not
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToTestAccount(emailAddress)));
    // other code ...
}
```

Calling the method `ToTestAccount()` to add the "test-" in the email address.

```
private string ToTestAccount(string emailAddress)
{
    var userAlias = emailAddress.Split('@')[0];
    var host = emailAddress.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0];
    var hostDomain = emailAddress.Split('@')[1];
    var indexOfDot = hostDomain.IndexOf('.');
    var domain = hostDomain.Substring(indexOfDot, hostDomain.Length - indexOfDot);
    return userAlias + "@test-" + host + domain;
}
```

The functionality produce my expected result. Sample data and expected output:

```
Email Address             | Expected
----------------------------------------------------------
arulkumar@gmail.com       | arulkumar@test-gmail.com
arul.kumar@gmail.com      | arul.kumar@test-gmail.com
arulkumar4@gmail.co.in    | arulkumar4@test-gmail.co.in
arul.kumar4@gmail.co.in   | arul.kumar4@test-gmail.co.in
```

But is there any other way to achieve the expected result, I mean using less string funtions or the best practice to achieve it?

C# Fiddle for the same: https://rextester.com/LPZI50439

<sub>For some reason, I'm not able to use `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` option, so I'm triggering the actual email.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MailAddress` properties which would result in **less** string manipulation and handle some of the weird varieties of valid email addresses.

```
private string ToTestAccount(string emailAddress)
{
    var originalEmailAddress = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
    return $"{originalEmailAddress.User}@test-{originalEmailAddress.Host}";
}
```

Or if you need to support display names you could have an extension method:

```
public static MailAddress Testing(this MailAddress address)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.DisplayName) 
        ? new MailAddress($"{address.User}@test-{address.Host}")
        : new MailAddress($"{address.User}@test-{address.Host}", address.DisplayName);
}
```

Which would allow usage like this:

```
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    // already valided the "emailAddress" is the valid one or not
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress).Testing()));
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(aDifferentEmailAddress, displayName).Testing()));
    // other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace in your case.

```
private string ToTestAccount(string emailAddress)
{
    return emailAddress == null ? emailAddress : emailAddress.Replace("@","@test-");
}
```

Please note that this solution is valid only in case if you need not to deliver the message to the real user. If you need to change domain to deliver it it may not work as email may contain more than one @ symbol. As @andyb952 mentioned in a comment it's very rare but possible.

Comment: There is actually no specific limit on @ characters.

"stupid.(),:;<>[]\".WEIRD.\"email@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com is a valid address.

See also, the Wikipedia page on the subject. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: @andyb952 You absolutely right but the initial goal is not to deliver this email to the real user. It will be achieved.